# How to unite 3 files in one table?

Tags: php, mysql, text-files

I have a test script, that generate txt file with answers. And have 2 txt files with the correct answers. I want:
1) Unite all files in one table, like:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>№ of question</td>
<td>data from file 1</td>
<td>data from file 2</td>
<td>data from file 3</td>
</tr>
...
</table>
```

2) I want to replace id in this files on text from DB (MySQL). I have table with question and answers with similar id (like in txt files).

All files have structure like:

```
1|3
2|4
3|1
```

where first number - is id of a question, and second is a variant of answer.

I start coding, but don't know how to include data from files:

```
// Slect from DB
$qsel=mysql_query("SELECT `qid`, `qtext` from `questions` ORDER BY `qid`");

// Open file 1 
$key1=fopen("data/test_1_key1.txt", "r");
$k1=explode("/r/n", $key1);

// Open file 2 
$key2=fopen("data/test_1_key2.txt", "r");
$k2=explode("/r/n", $key2);

$rtable='<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
    <tr>
      <th width="40%">Q</th>
      <th width="20%">A 1</th>
      <th width="20%">A 2</th>
      <th width="20%">NAME</th>
    </tr>';
  while($q=mysql_fetch_row($qsel))
  {

    $rtable.='<tr><td><b>'.$q['1'].'</b></td>'; 
    $rtable.='<td>data from file 1</td>'; 
    $rtable.='<td>data from file 2</td>'; 
    $rtable.='<td></td>'; 
  }
  echo '</table>'.$rtable;
```

Comment: What have you already done? Are The rows in the files ordered? Is There any missing one?

Comment: Yes, all files are sorted by first id. Without missing. I don't know, how to start generate a table with td from 3x files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first fetch the textfiles and convert it into indexed array:

```
$tmp1 = file('text1.txt');
$data1 = array();
foeach($tmp1 as $line)
{
    list($key1, $val1) = explode("|", $line);
    $data1[$key1] = $val1;
}
```

and then, on mysql fetch loop, just use the indexed array:

```
while($q=mysql_fetch_row($qsel))
{

    $rtable.='<tr><td><b>'.$q['1'].'</b></td>'; 
    $rtable.='<td>' . ( isset( $data1[ $q['0'] ] ) ? $data1[ $q['0'] ] : '' ) . '</td>'; 
    $rtable.='<td>data from file 2</td>'; 
    $rtable.='<td></td>'; 
}
```

Comment: sorry, there's minor bug in this line `$data1 = array();`. Also, by nothing displays, is it only display table header without data or no output at all?

Comment: I guessed about array, but not work( Table shows without `<td></td>` that we want to show.

Comment: Problem with `$data1[ $q['qid'] ]` why we output row? Neede a line from file!

Comment: you need a line from file, but what line? If you look close enough, `$data1` is indexed array with the index taken from first section of line file (the ID, as you noted above). To get the right data, you need to know what ID I'm looking right now, hence `$data1[ $q['qid'] ]`.

Comment: oh, btw, this is free service, I help you without me getting paid. Be-careful with *the* exclamation.

Comment: Sorry, i understand. How about output without compare by id, because lines ordered like rows in table. i try: $file1 = `file('data/test_1_key1.txt');
 for($i=0; $i < count($file1); $i++)
    {
   $key1=explode('|',$file1[$i]);
    }` and `$key1[1]` but it show only first line...

Comment: oh, come on! I think you need to get a class in basic PHP (to be exact, the array class). Look again, `$data1` is already filled with whatever `ID|value` from your text file. Therefore, it doesn't matter how you sort the result from database. Because, on every table row ( the `while($q=mysql_fetch_row($qsel))`) `$data1` is being checked, is it containing valud for current id (hence, `isset( $data1[ $q['qid'] ] )`)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4653/discussion-between-silent-and-vladimir)